# Batch Loop Last Step

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file

first time poster (please be kind if answer exists elsewhere, I could not find). I am sure there are 20,000 other more modern ways to accomplish the below, but I have always wanted an answer to this.

What I am looking to do is run a loop and then at the end of the loop (done), run a final step, separate from the loop. I am hoping someone can point out my simple mindedness.

Thank you all in advance.

Here is my batch.....

```
for /f "eol=#" %%i in (\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push.txt) do call :sub "%%i"

:sub

if exist "\\%1\c$\vm\isovm\09132013.txt" goto good
goto bad
goto end

:good
echo %1     good    >> \\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
goto end

:bad
echo %1     bad >> \\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
goto end

:end


:done
\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
```

Comment: What do you exactly intend to do with `\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the line at the end of your script does but you could move it to execute it at the end of the loop like this:

```
for /f "eol=#" %%i in (\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push.txt) do call :sub "%%i"

\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
goto end

:sub

if exist "\\%1\c$\vm\isovm\09132013.txt" goto good
goto bad

:good
echo %1     good    >> \\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
goto end

:bad
echo %1     bad >> \\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
goto end

:end
```

Furthermore I think you could simplify it like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "eol=#" %%i in (\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push.txt) do (
    if exist "\\%%i\c$\vm\isovm\09132013.txt" (
        echo %%i     good >> \\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
    ) else (
        echo %%i     bad >> \\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
    )
)

\\server\ops\!ReinsDeploy\WindowsXPMODE\isovm-push-confirm.txt
```

Although it's been a while already since I last created a cmd.exe script so I could just hope that it would work.

Comment: konsole... genius. Although you say it has been a while.... you still got it. Your second option was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Ant Welcome and thanks :) I hope you could accept the answer. I think it's the checkmark :)